# How to force absolute import in all modules

Tags: python, import

I'm currently using python 2.7.3.

I've added an import hook to sys.meta_path that only implements the find_module function; it goes something like this:

```
class SvnImporter(object):
    def find_module(self, fullname, *args):
        if fullname.split(".")[0] == "load_from_svn":
            exported_parent_dir = self.export_from_svn(fullname)
            sys.path.append(exported_parent_dir)
        return None
```

All `SvnImporter` does is export the desired module from svn, and add it to sys.path so that it could be imported via normal methods.

The problem I'm having is that all of these normally-imported modules are ALL doing relative imports, unless I specifically put

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the start of *every* file. The error I'm seeing says something like:

```
module "load_from_svn.module1.socket" could not be loaded
```

I already have `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the start of the main script - I thought this turned on absolute_import for all subsequently loaded modules? How do I force all modules to use absolute imports and not relative imports?

Comment: `from __future__` imports only ever apply to current module. Short of switching to Python 3, you cannot force this on any other module.

Comment: If future statements applied to other modules, any unrelated code that wasn't written to use the new semantics would fail catastrophically. Preventing that is the reason future statements exist.

Comment: ah, gotcha thanks for the clarification :^)  that was a rather large oversight on my part - make it an answer?

Comment: oh, wait - in the __init__.py of the main load_from_svn module, I *do* have from __future__ import absolute_import

Comment: That only applies to `__init__.py`.